# Displaying a Toast notification in Android framework

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to modify the Android framework by displaying an Toast notification in the PasswordUnlockScreen.java file when a password verification is done. I've added the following line of code in verifyPasswordAndUnlock()

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verifying password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, I get the build error:

```
frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PasswordUnlockScreen.java:166: cannot find symbol symbol  : method getApplicationContext()
location: class com.android.internal.policy.impl.PasswordUnlockScreen
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verifying password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What should I use as the context instead of getApplicationContext()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Toast.makeText(PasswordUnlockScreen.this, "Verifying password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```