# OnNewIntent does not show Toast

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying a Toast notification in Android framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304267/displaying-a-toast-notification-in-android-framework)

I have an activity and in onResume there is the following Code:

```
super.onResume();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null,null);
```

In the onNewIntent(Intent intent) function I have:

```
super.onNewIntent(intent);
setIntent(intent)
..
...

Toast.makeText....
```

But the Toast does not show up - does someone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: `Toast.makeText()` only, or `Toast.makeText().show()`?  Without the latter it won't display!

Comment: Wait... you have a problem with the `Toast.makeText()` not working but you're not going to show us that particular line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the Toast.makeText does not show up - someone a solution for this
>   problem?

Most likely you forgot call `show()` method.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
CharSequence text = "Your Text";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, duration);
```

and then just use `toast.show();` whenever you want to show your message.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes Thanks guys, I forgot the show() call here on this - I thought the problem was maybe something because of the UI-Thread in background or don't know. Thanks very much for the fast help :)

Comment: 0gravity: Please don't post the same answer on more than one question. If they are duplicates, flag them. If they are not, then tailor your question towards what the asker is asking.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks.